# Android + Volley: how to get image bitmap using ImageLoader?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-volley, image-loading

I'm trying to get images for list view using Volley Library. I created simple HTTP helper with the following method.

```
/**
     * Processing Image request and gets the image with given URL
     */
    public Bitmap makeImageRequest(String url) {
        ImageLoader il = new ImageLoader(queue, new BitmapLruCache());
        il.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
               mBitmap =  processImageResponse(response);

            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(Constants.Global.ERROR, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                mBitmap = null;
            }
        });
        return mBitmap;
    }
```

But problem is that:

```
new BitmapLruCache()
```

Method is not recognized.

So i tried to create ImageLoader using the following code which i found on the URL:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
```

But in thos code i cannot find out where to get

```
AppController
```

Because the method code is triggered from the custom

```
public class HttpHelperClass
```

And called from the activity using the:

```
// Try to load remote image from URL
        Bitmap bm = http.makeImageRequest("http://camranger.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Android-Icon.png");
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Is it the right approach how to load images and how can i repair my code to make succcessfull request?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `makeImageRequest` method will always return `null` because it takes some time for the `onResponse` or `onErrorResponse` listeners to get called but you return the `mBitmap` immidately!

If you want to use Volley's `ImageLoader` you'd better get image inside your activity or ... not from another class like your `HttpHelperClass`.

Also `AppController` is a class that extends `Application` and **you should create it yourself**. (It's in your [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) link. **Section 3. Creating Volley Singleton class**)

And also for caching images you should not create a new `ImageLoader` everytime because in this way the caching gets meaningless. You should get that from your `AppController` class.

Furthermore I suggest you using **[Picasso](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwis08jbpcTHAhWHiRoKHXc-BFk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsquare%2Fpicasso&ei=k2fcVey9HYeTavf8kMgF&usg=AFQjCNGmLkWW5mteK1QB_03TgneE7bN7vQ&sig2=0et_aoi7Zw-jN3APhiuSug)** because it's way better that **`Volley`** in image loading and a lot easier!
With `Picasso` you only need to call the following line to load an image from web into an `ImageView`:

`Picasso.with(context).load(urlString).to(imageView);`